# PHP ini error reporting not working. Error 500 all parse/syntax errors

Tags: php, iis-8

Have PHP 5.5.8 running with IIS 8.  For some reason, since I have updated PHP, I get no error messages, just an error 500 page.  Pages with no errors function correctly.

I have set in the php.ini (in `c:\php\php.ini`) as follows

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = on
```

I have the cgi mappings in IIS8 set to `c:\php\php-cgi.exe` for `*.php` extensions

The php install is in `c:\php`  Here is the `phpinfo()`

one strange item at the bottom is: Environment Path C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4  -- there is no php or folder here ANYMORE.  And the path variable has been changed to c:\php.  Why is the old install location still showing???

```
PHP Version 5.5.8

System  Windows NT computername 6.2 build 9200 (Windows Server 2012 Standard Edition) i586

Build Date  Jan 8 2014 15:26:19

Compiler    MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)

Architecture    x86

Configure Command   cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-
debug-pack" "--disable-zts" "--disable-isapi" "--disable-nsapi" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared" "--with-enchant=shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--disable-static-analyze" "--with-pgo"

Server API  CGI/FastCGI

Virtual Directory Support   disabled

Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\Windows

Loaded Configuration File   C:\PHP\php.ini

Scan this dir for additional .ini files     (none)

Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
```

Is there something in IIS that is overriding the display error page?  I had no issues with an older version of php.

Comment: I have a very similar issue - No idea PHP 5.4 works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, if you have:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = on
log_errors = on
```

then you get the ERROR 500 page for ALL errors

Just change only

```
log_errors = off
```

then you are good to go